# NodeJs : why my Writablestream does not close before end of program?

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a NodeJS script that I use to write JSON objects to file :

```
var reWriteCodes = function(arrayCodes, pathFileCodes, fs, typereWriteCodes, cb) {
  console.log("message : "+ typereWriteCodes);
  var codesStream = fs.createWriteStream(pathFileCodes, {'flags': 'w'});
  codesStream.on('finish', () => {
    console.log("the stream is closed")
    if (typereWriteCodes === 0) {
        cb();
    } 
  });
  var jsonToWrite = { "liste_codes" : arrayCodes};
  codesStream.write(JSON.stringify(jsonToWrite));
  codesStream.end();
}
```

This function is called twiced (first with typereWriteCodes = 0 then with typereWriteCodes = 1, inside the callback function : cb) with two different files.

The first call ends fine, my file is saved and the message "the stream is closed" displays in the console. But in the second call (which is the last operation of the program), my file is not saved correctly (the file is empty) and the message "the stream is closed" is not triggerd. Also, I get this message :

> events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ''
>       at Error (native)

I have the feeling that the app is closing before the stream could end correctly ... But I do not know how I can do this correctly. Could you help me with this issue ? Any help appreciated.

Comment: As long as you're not forcefully exiting or calling your `reWriteCodes()` from an `exit` event handler, it won't exit before the stream finishes. Have you verified the contents of `pathFileCodes` for the problematic attempt?

Comment: The path I use is correct, i double checked that. I also think it is strange that I have no path shown in the error message (as i tried to google it and each time I saw a path indicated).

Comment: just to be sure, what do you mean by "problematic attempt" ?

Comment: The one that causes the error.

Comment: Yes, I checked the path (which is a Linux absolute path). I could add that before the script run, the file is full (some kB) and by the end of the script (error), the file is empty ...